# How to reproduce NetworkError (DOM Exception 19) when using XmltHttpRequest()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code that triggers a NetworkError on very rare occasions:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
     request.open("POST", server, false);
}
catch (err) {
    return;
}
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");    
var sending = xmlrpc.writeCall(method, params);
try {
    request.send(sending);
}
catch(e) {
    if (e.name == 'NetworkError') {
        var currentDate = '[' + new Date().toTimeString() + '] ';
        console.log(currentDate + "  Network Error: " + e.message);
        throw el
    }
}
```

I added the try..catch block so I can see the time of the error in the console log. However, I don't know what triggers it, it seems like it is just happens when the JavaScript engine in the browser has a network exception.

The question is how do I **force** this NetworkError so I can try and maybe add retries.

**EDIT**: Added request object code.

Comment: Show your `request` Object please.

Comment: @PHPglue: Sorry about that. Added code.

Comment: Do you just want to add `finally{}` after `catch{}`?

Comment: @PHPglue: What I would like to do is force this error during testing so I can see how the code will behave.

Comment: If you use a `finally` clause the behavior will happen no matter what. If you want something to happen under a condition then use one like: `if()`.

Comment: @PHPglue: Actually, won't be it be synchronous since I opened the request object by passing 'false' to boolean async parameter in request.open.

Comment: I think that could be your problem. When using an `XMLHttpRequest` Object's `.open()` method you set asynch to `false`. If the Sever has a glitch, there is really no `onreadystatechange` to test for, so the script fails. Maybe you would jam it on purpose from the Server side with a large amount of data.

Comment: @PHPglue: Yes, I wouldn't be surprised if that's the problem. However, the entire code base was done with this synchronous assumption in mind by the developers. Instead of throwing errors, can I put that block in a loop and retry the request multiple times?

Comment: Asynchronous code would not throw errors, necessarily. Consider: `request.onreadystatechange = function(){if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){something.innerHTML = request.responseText;}}`. That code waits until you have a good response, then assigns a String to `something` node.

Comment: @PHPglue: Does this work with the synchronous code that I have?